# EF Migrations: Add additional indirection inbetween an existing 1-to-n relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, database-migration

Imagine this scenario: A person owns a set of cars. Currently I have:

> User (1) -- (N) Cars

Now I want to modify my tables to have a user own garages instead of cars and the garages own a subset of cars, i.e. add a simple additional indirection:

> User (1) -- (N) Garages (1) -- (N) Cars

The actual data can be dropped that is okay. It is simply that theres other parts to that database that contain data that should be kept. This part is complety isolated and can be erased. The example is made up, because I am unsure what I can tell but it is really that simple.

I have no clue about migrations and struggle hard with this. Thanks a lot for any help, I appreciate it!

Edit: What I have is:

```
public class OwnerEntity
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set;}
  public List<CarEntity> OwnedCars { get; set; }
  // Rather would have:
  // public List<GarageEntity> OwnedGarages { get; set; }
}

public class CarEntity
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  [Required]
  public OwnerEntity Owner { get; set; }
  public Guid OwnerId { get; set; }
  // Would not be directly owned anymore but would have a garage as an owner

  [Required]
  public string ModelDescr { get; set; }
}
// In the db context
public DbSet<OwnerEntity> Owners { get; set; }
public DbSet<CarEntity> Cars { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder model)
{
  // This would simply duplicate. Once for Car <-> Garage and once for Garage <-> Owner entitities
  model.Entity<CarEntity>()
                .HasOne(x => x.Owner)
                .WithMany(x => x.OwnedCars)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

The main problem I have when I try to change something here is: The database still keeps the old tables and schema. Without dropping it there appear coinflicts (kind of expected). 
There are also more entities following attached to Car (to use my example) that I want to keep (their schema). I tried to comment out the DBSets to have EF drop the tables by itself and then do my changes and have it do the actual migration but that isn't really working it's to much work and just stupid..
Hope that helps more!

Comment: If it is a very simple setup maybe you could alter the names and post some kind of micro version of what you want us to help with. Without disclosing specific data of your employer. It is so much easier to answer specific questions than very abstract ones. Also are you using code-first or database-first approach?

Comment: basically this has nothing to do with migrations in first place. you need to know how you would solve this with plain SQL (or whatever your database is).

Comment: after you know how to do it in SQL it is basically disabling some indexes (as i said: it is the same as you would do it in SQL)

Comment: I have edited the question. I don't work with SQL directly. Everything is done in code and It rather keep it that way.

Comment: i understand that. but when you want to add a table in the middle you need to migrate your data to that new schema. migrations does NOT do that for you, you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: Are you looking for something like code first migrations: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/ ? It can generate the changes to the DB schema based on the changes to your code. It wont automatically migrate the data for you, but it if you know your way around SQL, you can easily write, and include it in the migrations yourself.

Comment: You have to make own entities... than make migration (u can use Package manager console add-migration name... than u can remove-migration if necessary) But in gods sake don't delete migrations with delete button in explorer.. than u have to check db.. there could be generated table with migrations used on table and you'll have to delete those, who are not used.. Maybe it could be ur problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue was that there were still existing elements in the tables, where I was trying to change foreign key relationships.
The solution was very simple: I have created an empty migration and simply erased all the content of those tables manually (due to cascading delete behaviour I only had to delete one table).

After this I could alter any columns the way I wanted because there was no data left to cause conflicts. Quite a stupid problem but it, I couldn't wrap my head around it for quite a while.